# how to get updated value of a variable from setInterval function

Tags: javascript, setinterval

```js
var data = Math.random()

setInterval(function interval() {
  console.log(data)
}, 1500)
```

I want to get the updated value of `var data` from `setinterval` function, but I'm not able to get the updated value of `var data`, don't change this line

`var data = Math.random()`

This line is mandatory. I can't change this line somehow. How can I get the updated value?

Comment: There is no update in your value

Comment: You are assigning some random value to your variable **only once**, and expecting it to be new each time when your ``setInterval`` executes.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to convert it to a function, to be recalculated in each `setInterval`:

```js
const data = () => Math.random();

setInterval(function interval() {
  console.log(data());
}, 1500);
```

Comment: I know this basic. but my main question is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66375798/how-to-get-updated-value-of-react-usestate-hook-from-setinterval-function-in-hig please solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

```
var data = Math.random()

setInterval(function interval(){
console.log(data)
},1500)
```

In this case data variable is not updated in each interval thats why this data is printing same value

Other way to do this :

```
setInterval(function interval(){
    var data = Math.random()
    console.log(data)
    },1500)
```

Or you can define a function for random number in top and you can call in inside of interval

Comment: that's not possible to define the data variable inside setInterval. because in my code, i fetch some data from api & use the data outside of setinterval. & now i have to get the same api data inside the setInterval.. how its possible

Comment: I know this basic. but my main question is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66375798/how-to-get-updated-value-of-react-usestate-hook-from-setinterval-function-in-hig please solve this problem